# MySQL Query doesn't update rows

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a weird problem here. I've been trying to find out whats wrong for several hours now. I've got a function that should update a table in my database and set the "date_vente" (date_sold for english) to NOW(). The query is mighty simple but it keeps reporting 1 matched row, 0 changed.

Problem is, the data should be changed. If i run the query manually, it works fine, if i run it from the php app, it fails...

```
//Marque le panier comme vendu
$sqlstring = "UPDATE ".$prefix_tables_panier."paniers SET date_vente = NOW() WHERE no_panier = ".$data_panier["no_panier"];
$result = mysql_query($sqlstring, $conn_panier);
echo $sqlstring.'<br>';
echo mysql_affected_rows($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_error($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_errno($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_error($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_info($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_stat($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
```

And the output is

```
UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente = NOW() WHERE no_panier = 840
0

0
resource(5) of type (mysql link)
string(0) ""
string(40) "Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0"
string(145) "Uptime: 1640423 Threads: 5 Questions: 39673341 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1132 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 235 Queries per second avg: 24.185" 7
```

The problem is it should write a value of NOW to the table containing the baskets but it is not. And no, it's not because of a wrong connection, the same connection id (var_dumped it) is used in the function just before, calling it and they both have the same id, the connection is still open and there is a value of "0000-00-00 00:00:00" in the column i'm trying to update...

Can anyone give me some more hints to look at?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente = NOW() WHERE no_panier = 840
0

0
resource(5) of type (mysql link)
string(0) ""
string(40) "Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0"
string(145) "Uptime: 1641927 Threads: 5 Questions: 39681590 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1132 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 235 Queries per second avg: 24.168"

UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente = "2011-12-28 12:00:17" WHERE no_panier = 840
1

0
resource(5) of type (mysql link)
string(0) ""
string(40) "Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0"
string(145) "Uptime: 1641927 Threads: 5 Questions: 39681591 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1132 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 235 Queries per second avg: 24.168"
go
```

This is getting weird, VERY VERY WEIRD!

---

**UPDATE #2**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `panier_paniers` (
  `no_panier` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `client_prenom` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_nom` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_entreprise` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `client_adresse` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_ville` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_province_etat` char(2) default NULL,
  `client_pays` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_code_postal_zip` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_telephone` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_type_telephone` enum('domicile','travail','cellulaire') NOT NULL default 'domicile',
  `client_telecopieur` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `client_courriel` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_mailinglist_from` datetime default NULL,
  `client_langue` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_no_client` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `expedition_mode` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `expedition_no_livraison` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `expedition_produit` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `expedition_produit_no_compte` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `expedition_frais_livraison` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `expedition_frais_manut` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `expedition_assurance` char(1) NOT NULL default 'X',
  `expedition_signature` char(1) NOT NULL default 'X',
  `expedition_conf_livraison` char(1) NOT NULL default 'X',
  `expedition_emballage` text,
  `expedition_no_suivi` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `expedition_prenom` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `expedition_nom` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `expedition_entreprise` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `expedition_adresse` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `expedition_ville` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `expedition_province_etat` char(2) default NULL,
  `expedition_pays` char(2) default NULL,
  `expedition_code_postal_zip` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `expedition_telephone` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `expedition_type_telephone` enum('domicile','travail','cellulaire') NOT NULL default 'domicile',
  `expedition_exporte_ups_connect` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `expedition_mis_a_jour_ups_connect` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `paiement_mode` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `paiement_no_paiement` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `paiement_numero_taxe_fed` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `paiement_numero_taxe_prov` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `paiement_numeros_taxes_speciales` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `paiement_numero_po` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `paiement_numero_bon` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `paiement_cc_pa_trnid` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `paiement_cc_pa_montant` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `paiement_cc_capture` text,
  `paiement_desjardins_TxID` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `paiement_desjardins_date_envoi` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_creation` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ip_creation` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `host_creation` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `date_vente` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_annulee` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_completee` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_inventaire` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_acceptation` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `note` text,
  `note_client` text,
  `no_utilisateur` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`no_panier`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=841 ;
```

---

**UPDATE #3**

Ok, look at this spooky thing:

```
//Marque le panier comme vendu
$sqlstring = 'UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente = NOW() WHERE no_panier = '.$data_panier["no_panier"];
$result = mysql_query($sqlstring, $conn_panier);
echo $sqlstring.'<br>';
echo mysql_affected_rows($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_error($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_errno($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_error($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_info($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_stat($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';

$sqlstring='UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente  = "2011-12-28 10:09:12" WHERE no_panier = '.$data_panier["no_panier"];
mysql_query($sqlstring, $conn_panier);
echo $sqlstring.'<br>';
echo mysql_affected_rows($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_error($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_errno($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_error($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_info($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_stat($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
```

As you can see, both should be valid, the first one will not update anything, the second does update the row. Switch around and test again:

```
$sqlstring='UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente  = "2011-12-28 10:09:12" WHERE no_panier = '.$data_panier["no_panier"];
mysql_query($sqlstring, $conn_panier);
echo $sqlstring.'<br>';
echo mysql_affected_rows($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_error($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_errno($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_error($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_info($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_stat($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';

//Marque le panier comme vendu
$sqlstring = 'UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente = NOW() WHERE no_panier = '.$data_panier["no_panier"];
$result = mysql_query($sqlstring, $conn_panier);
echo $sqlstring.'<br>';
echo mysql_affected_rows($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_error($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
echo mysql_errno($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump($conn_panier); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_error($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_info($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
var_dump(mysql_stat($conn_panier)); echo '<br>';
```

RESULT:

```
UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente = "2011-12-28 10:09:12" WHERE no_panier = 840
1

0
resource(5) of type (mysql link)
string(0) ""
string(40) "Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0"
string(145) "Uptime: 1643141 Threads: 5 Questions: 39713580 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1286 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 219 Queries per second avg: 24.169"
UPDATE panier_paniers SET date_vente = NOW() WHERE no_panier = 840
1

0
resource(5) of type (mysql link)
string(0) ""
string(40) "Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0"
string(145) "Uptime: 1643141 Threads: 5 Questions: 39713581 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1286 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 219 Queries per second avg: 24.169"
```

Now both updates work... I tried a verify, repair and optimize to see if it wasn't a corruption issue, nothing changed...

Comment: Does it work if you run the query in your favourite MySQL client? What's the exact column type?

Comment: Column type is DATETIME and yes it works if i run it manually from phpmyadmin or heidisql... Remember though, it FINDS the row, it matches it, so it's not a wrong connection issue...

Comment: What's the probability of you viewing the wrong record?

Comment: Does the user that is used for connection have the privilege to `UPDATE` that table?

Comment: ypercube: yes, i rarely work with table/column specific privileges

Comment: N.B.: 0%, i am in the right record and my app doesn't see it updated, thats why i'm trying to fix the problem, else i wouldnt be trying to fix that problem

Comment: WHat version of MYSQL and what OS?

Comment: Even better, i tried putting another query right after that updates ANOTHER field on the SAME row. And it works...

Comment: "my app doesn't see it updated". Perhaps the app does not get the new data. Have you tried refreshing/reloading the table in the app?

Comment: Just for testing purposes, what happens when you provide a date string like `SET date_vente='2011-12-28 12:00:00'` ?

Comment: mysql: 5.0.92-50-log, php: latest 5.2.17

Comment: One more question: Is is a `date` or a `datetime` column? If it's a `date`, then it's normal.

Comment: Can we see the complete `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: See second post and everywhere i say its a DATETIME and 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: @Fluff: Updated, look at the post to get the CREATE TABLE

Comment: Hm, something between interesting and spooky... a) what happens when you use `SYSDATE()` or `Curdate()` instead of `Now()`? What is the result of the query `"SELECT Now() as now, date_vente FROM panier_paniers WHERE no_panier=840"` (via php _and_ heidisql) ?

Comment: @Volkerk: i'll check that out, meanwhile, look at this, i INVERT the two blocks, the one that is hardcoded goes on top and the dynamic one with the NOW() or a date build with date('Y-m-d G:i:s') and it works on both. I put the semi-static bloc below and we go back to the old version where the first dynamic query doesn't work but the second works... SPOOKY

Comment: Hope you can post the `CREATE TABLE` script, as well as any triggers that you might have set for this table..

Comment: @VolkerK: It works with CURDATE but not with SYSDATE(), NOW() or a manually built date using date('Y-m-d G:i:s'). More interresting is the fact that i'll post in UPDATE #3 up there... Gimme 2 minutes to format and paste

Comment: @Nonym: Done, look at update #2

Comment: What mysql client are you using to view the values after each test? Just for grins - try exit and restart the client.

Comment: @ethrbunny: PHPMyAdmin 3.4.5 and i do a CTRL F5 everytime i reload the page just to make sure. Anyway php reports nothing was changed. I think it's something to do with the mysql lib on the server. i'll go see what version is installed...

Comment: mysql
MySQL Support enabled
Active Persistent Links  0
Active Links  0
Client API version  5.0.92
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE  external
MYSQL_SOCKET  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE  -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient

Comment: I'd fire up a virtual machine with another mysql server version ;-)

Comment: Also - do a 'select now()' in your code and see what's returned.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now ---> makes it look like 'now()' can be overridden at the server level.

Comment: @everyone: I did an isolation test, it seems it might be something else between the connection and the first query we are debugging, cause i took the advice of my coworker and isolated the whole code into a test.php file with only the connection and the query and it works... So i'll have the look in the previous functions what is happening. this is strange... it was working the other day and stopped suddenly

Comment: OMG, such shame, the problem seemed to be there... I'm debugging a catalog made inhouse by other programmers, i didn't see it but someone put an exact same update right before calling the function that used to do it. So i was debugging something that was not theoretically, but furthermore, if i look below, there was an error in the logic that forced another query to reset the value to 0000-00-00, so i thought i had a problem at the wrong place because of two bad inhouse coding practice. Sorry all but thank you for the time you spent...

Comment: Remember, NOW() returns the MYSQL SERVER date and time, the second query maybe is defining a different time from NOW() because is running into a different server or timezone (CURDATE returns only DATE, no time, and must change the value). As you said before, you really have something else between the connection and the first query who set the time to current NOW() value to this entry.

Comment: @PauloH. Thanks for your input, i'm all aware of those, i'm seriously going to track down those two programmers that built that catalog and kill them. Then i'll start a pilgrimmage and become an hermit... will be easier that way... O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was after all an issue with logic and bad coding practices. The problem came from the previous programmers who liked to have no structure and place code in weird places. I found the error outside of the scope of what we where looking for.

I might say, if you get such an error, look for flaws in your code where a same query could be executed right before the current one that SEEMS to fail. That will save you HOURS of trouble looking for a solution that doesn't pertain to the problem at hand.

Comment: Your co-worker that suggested the isolation test - buy him / her a drink.

Comment: You could add the link to `UPDATE` documantatio and the *`"If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it."`* which means that if your Update statement finds matching rows but does not update them, better look for other code (that runs before yours or a trigger) that may be also updating.